# Swift not conforming to Objective-C protocol

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

So I'm attempting to follow a tutorial from wsdl2code where they are implementing the obj-c protocols in the app delegate ( the whole project is in objective-c).

I'm trying to recreate it in swift but I keep getting told that I'm not conforming to the protocol. I've made sure that the types used in the swift versions of the methods correctly swap over from objective-c to swift.

Here's the objective-c header

```
#ifndef _Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate
#define _Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate
@protocol Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate
//if service recieve an error this method will be called
-(void)proxyRecievedError:(NSException*)ex InMethod:(NSString*)method;
//proxy finished, (id)data is the object of the relevant method service
-(void)proxydidFinishLoadingData:(id)data InMethod:(NSString*)method;
@end
#endif
```

Here's my swift code

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate {

    // MARK: Proxy protocol methods

    func proxydidFinishLoadingData(data: AnyObject!, inMethod method: String!) {
        print("Service \(method) done!")
    }

    func proxyRecievedError(ex: NSException!, inMethod method: String!) {
        print("Exception in service \(method)")
    }
```

Comment: In addition to what Ethan points out below, the method names are poorly named (...InMethod) in the ObjC header, but in the swift you're using "inMethod"

Comment: That's what xcode is demanding. It camel cases it and if I change it then it tells me it is not like the method

Answer (score 1):

you should implement the protocol like this, 'Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate' forget to implement the 'NSObject' protocol

```
@protocol Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate <NSObject>
//if service recieve an error this method will be called
- (void)proxyRecievedError:(NSException*)ex inMethod:(NSString*)method;
//proxy finished, (id)data is the object of the relevant method service
- (void)proxydidFinishLoadingData:(id)data inMethod:(NSString*)method;
@end

func proxydidFinishLoadingData(data: AnyObject!, inMethod method: String!) {

}

func proxyRecievedError(ex: NSException!, inMethod method: String!) {

}
```

Comment: Didn't work. It still says that it is not being conformed to.

Comment: Did both of you forget to change `String` to `NSString` ? also `inMethod` vs `InMethod`

Comment: I have to say that you wrote the wrong 'Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate', you are leadingi the wrong direction at the beginning. update my reply, works fine in my project.